# How can I remove `let _ : () = ...`?

Tags: rust

Here is my code, and this works:

```
extern crate redis;

// connect to redis
fn establish_connection() -> redis::Connection {
    let client = redis::Client::open("redis://ip:port/0").unwrap();
    client.get_connection().unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let con : redis::Connection = establish_connection();
    let _ : () = redis::cmd("RANDOMKEY").query(&con).unwrap();
}
```

But this one doesn't work:

```
//...

fn main() {
    let con : redis::Connection = establish_connection();
    redis::cmd("RANDOMKEY").query(&con).unwrap();
}
```

It raises an error while compiling:

```
error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required [E0282]
    redis::cmd("FLUSHALL").query(&con).unwrap();
                           ^~~~~
help: run `rustc --explain E0282` to see a detailed explanation
```

Do I have to write `let _ : () = ...`? How can I remove it?

Comment: I think this should work: `redis::cmd("RANDOMKEY").query::<()>(&con).unwrap();`.

Comment: Yes it works. Cool! Would you write an answer that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`redis::Cmd::query` is defined as:

```
fn query<T: FromRedisValue>(&self, con: &ConnectionLike) -> RedisResult<T>
```

You just need to make the `T` here `()` to get the same behaviour as annotating the value of `query(...).unwrap()` to be `T`. This should work:

```
redis::cmd("RANDOMKEY").query::<()>(&con).unwrap();
```

Comment: This is correct, but I'd say the original version is more idiomatic most of the time.